# How to make Parts movable within a PartStack

Tags: eclipse, e4

I'm trying to figure out how to make the Part's movable within a Part Stack in e4.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you mean you want the part to be movable but only in the part stack rather than the whole application window?

Comment: yes, thats precisely wat i'm looking for. By default if i add parts to the 'part stack' they seem to be fixed. Unable to interchange the tabs by dragging around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To support drag and drop of parts you need the DndAddon and CleanupAddon specified in your Application.e4xmi.

The Class URIs are:

```
bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDAddon

bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.cleanupaddon.CleanupAddon
```

This requires the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt` plugin

Comment: +1 Am I the only one who feels this counterintuitive? This is the third time in 2 days I tried to find info on this, and finally found it. Gosh, I hope getting in on e4 is worth the trouble.

Comment: @ppeterka If you haven't already seen it look at Lars Vogel's [e4 tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html) or read his e4 book which is an extended version of the tutorial.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks in tha name of everyone who finds your comment, I'm addicted to Vogella's work since the early Eclipse 3, and if it was not for him, I would have likely torn out all the hair I still have... The article you linked is very comprehensive and I'd say a life saver for e4 (as it is usual for Lars's tutorials), however it lacked the mention of these two addons.

Comment: @ppeterka The book does mention them (section 20.3)