# Is Inter docking supported in e4?

Tags: eclipse, e4

Below UI is what i'm trying to achieve using e4 rcp.

```
L1 & L2 should be movable (or) dockable
View1 & View2 should be movable (or) dockable within L1.
```

I have got the solution for the first constraint from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031690/how-to-make-parts-movable-within-a-partstack)

Can we achieve the draggable (or) docking feature within L1 using e4?

[image: Application.e4XMI]

**EDIT:**

It seem's e4 doesn't have that support yet,

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1295324/?srch=jitendar#msg_1295324

Comment: I can do this in the Eclipse IDE which is an e4 app. I don't think you can restrict the drag to just L1.

Comment: ok. I tried to do the L1 ( i.e. Make L1 draggable & place draggable views View1,View2 inside L1), but can't figure how to do it using Applcation.e4xmi ( bcz I can't place a Part inside another Part). Any idea on how to do L1 atleast, if we can't restrict the drag to just L1.

Comment: I think L1 would be a PartSashContainer with Vertical orientation containing two PartStacks

Comment: If L1 is a PartSashContainer, i don't think i will be able to move L1 & L2 in the first place, right?